# Unity: Original resources from .apk build for android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on Unity and I have some custom fonts which I have imported in the Assets/Resources/Fonts folder. I am able to use these fonts well.

I know while compiling for Android, unity create some binary files like "450f876fa8a06e347b802bbbd5371ebe" for all the resources(like fonts, images, Models etc.) in project and puts it inside assets\bin\Data folder.

Basically We have some paid fonts and I have doubts that there may be people who are using our fonts without our permission. We want to check some apps we have doubts on. So I am looking for someway to access the resources.

- I want to know if its possible to get any information about the resources from these files. Information can be any thing like name of resource, type of resource, file extension of resource etc
- Is there some other way to achieve what I have mentioned above

Comment: Why do you need the information? It would be nice to explain exactly what you are doing. Maybe there is an easier solution.

Comment: We have some paid fonts and I have doubts that there may be people who are using our fonts without our permission. We want to check some apps we have doubts on. So I am looking for someway to access the resources

Comment: This question is not appropriate for SO.Give [Unity Assets Explorer](http://zenhax.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=36&start=20) and [DisUnity](https://github.com/ata4/disunity) a try. One of them should work for you.